# Cannot resolve hostname in docker desktop windows

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin, docker-desktop

I have setup docker-compose to run phpmyadmin and mysql. Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
networks:
    local_web_network:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    mysql_data:
        driver: local
services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0
        container_name: local_mysql
        restart: always
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: local_master
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
            MYSQL_USER: homestead
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
        volumes:
            - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - local_web_network
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: local_phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "8083:80"
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: local_mysql
            PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI: http://db.test
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        networks:
            - local_web_network
        extra_hosts:
            - 'db.test:127.0.0.1'
```

I have configured the windows hosts file with the below settings

```
127.0.0.1 db.test
```

I have successfully run the docker containers without any errors. I have tried accessing the `http://127.0.0.1:8083` or `http://db.test:8083` it works and displays the phpmyadmin login page.

But the problem here is, i am unable to access the page without specifying the port i.e `http://db.test`. How do i get this working without specifying the port?

Comment: Change the exposed port number of phpmyadmin service to 80. When you use `http://`, browser automatically add port `80` and if you use `https://` browser add `443`. There might be no other way to connect to `8083` without specifying port number.

Comment: @J.Song You should make this an answer a bit further below; you've correctly answered the question and deserve the upvotes :)